# Using v-template outside of listView NATIVESCRIPT-VUE

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I need to use a single v-template in my custom component like

```
<FlexboxLayout class="ticker-col" ref="tickercol">
      <v-template name="charttemplate">
         <Chart :chartData="chartData" />
      </v-template>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

As mentioned on official docs ([link](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/utilities/v-template/)), it says I have to use registerTemplate method. And I have to use a scopedSlot render function as 3rd parameter of this function. But I couldn't find out how to do this. My Chart component is still invisible.

```
mounted() {
const tickercol = this.$refs.tickercol;
tickercol.$templates.registerTemplate("charttemplate", null, 'what should be here?');
```

I'm not sure that I'm on the right way. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you setup a Playground where the issue can be reproduced.